# BlurEffect only on TextBox Content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to hide some information to an user according it's logging.
So I decide by code to add a BlurEffect to the TextBox if the use can't read the information.

But the BlurEffect is done on all the control not only on the content.
I have tried to get the content by code with no success.
(For information I have to managed TextBox, WatermarkTextBox, Infragistics components)

Did someone have an idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The modern version of "put a transparent window over your control and change what's underneath it" is the [AdornerDecorator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator.aspx). Or change the colors to make it hard to read. But consider if this is really necessary. Spies looking over your shoulder are rare, whereas it's fairly easy to log keystrokes or spy on the text box. Is fake security worth making the user's life difficult?

Comment: In fact this just to hide information to user according it's user/password.